# Is there a way to force Ubuntu use WPA with my adapter?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers, authentication, lubuntu

I've built-in WiFi adapter in my notebook (made 5 years ago). Latest (dated 5 years ago) Windows drivers allow it to use WPA.

I'm using Lubuntu 10.10 but it allow me to use only WEP (same situation with Ubuntu 10.04). Is there a way to fix it?

UPD: hardware info

```
:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Transmeta Corporation LongRun Northbridge (rev 03)
00:00.1 RAM memory: Transmeta Corporation SDRAM controller
00:00.2 RAM memory: Transmeta Corporation BIOS scratchpad
00:03.0 Modem: ALi Corporation M5457 AC'97 Modem Controller
00:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: ALi Corporation M5451 PCI AC-Link Controller Audio Device (rev 02)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: ALi Corporation M1533/M1535/M1543 PCI to ISA Bridge [Aladdin IV/V/V+]
00:09.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Radeon Mobility M6 LY
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
00:0b.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB (rev 43)
00:0b.1 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB (rev 43)
00:0b.2 USB Controller: NEC Corporation USB 2.0 (rev 04)
00:0c.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI4510 PC card Cardbus Controller (rev 02)
00:0c.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments PCI4510 IEEE-1394 Controller
00:0f.0 IDE interface: ALi Corporation M5229 IDE (rev c4)
00:11.0 Bridge: ALi Corporation M7101 Power Management Controller [PMU]


:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 124a:168b AirVast PRISM3 WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:3c00 D-Link Corp. [hex] AirPlus G DWL-G122 Wireless Adapter(rev.B1) [Ralink RT2500USB]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The problem is with **Bus 002 Device 002: ID 124a:168b AirVast PRISM3 WLAN Adapter**.

D-Link is external USB and works good. I use it to work with net.

UPD 2:

```
:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
prism2_usb            160970  0 
arc4                    1165  2 
rt2500usb              18049  0 
rt2x00usb               9779  1 rt2500usb
rt2x00lib              27275  2 rt2500usb,rt2x00usb
led_class               2633  1 rt2x00lib
mac80211              231541  2 rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
cfg80211              144470  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
psmouse                59033  0 
parport_pc             26058  0 
dm_crypt               11385  0 
ppdev                   5556  0 
snd_ali5451            15875  1 
snd_ac97_codec         99227  1 snd_ali5451
ac97_bus                1014  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm                71475  2 snd_ali5451,snd_ac97_codec
snd_seq_midi            4588  0 
snd_rawmidi            17783  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event      6047  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                47174  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              19067  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          5744  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
pcmcia                 35973  0 
snd                    49006  9 snd_ali5451,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
yenta_socket           21518  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            10566  1 yenta_socket
i2c_ali15x3             5190  0 
serio_raw               4022  0 
pcmcia_core            14657  3 pcmcia,yenta_socket,pcmcia_rsrc
i2c_ali1535             4865  0 
soundcore                880  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          7120  1 snd_pcm
lp                      7342  0 
parport                31492  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
dm_raid45              81721  0 
xor                    15136  1 dm_raid45
radeon                825934  2 
ttm                    56633  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         30200  1 radeon
drm                   168054  4 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
8139too                19581  0 
video                  18712  0 
firewire_ohci          21106  0 
efficeon_agp            4794  0 
8139cp                 16934  0 
output                  1883  1 video
pata_ali                7976  2 
firewire_core          46643  1 firewire_ohci
agpgart                32011  3 ttm,drm,efficeon_agp
mii                     4425  2 8139too,8139cp
i2c_algo_bit            5168  1 radeon
crc_itu_t               1383  1 firewire_core
```

UPD 3: is there a copatible driver with WPA support?

Comment: Can you please do an "lspci" in a terminal and add the output to your question?

Comment: The output of lsmod can be helpful too. This card is likely using the orinoco driver, but it doesn't hurt to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the below article, the driver does not support WPA.

http://wiki.debian.org/linux-wlan-ng

Look in the known issues section.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: WPA is impossible then in linux for my WiFi-Adapter...